# Metal defaultLibrary does not load .metal functions

Tags: ios, swift, metal

My metal default library does not contain the vertex and shader functions from the  .metal file of the same directory.

Then the library.makeFunction(name: ..) returns nil for both the vertex and shader functions that should be assigned to pipelineDescriptor vars.

The metal file & headers are copied from the Apple Sample App "BasicTexturing" ([Creating and Sampling Textures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/textures/creating_and_sampling_textures)).

The file APPLShaders.metal and APPLShaderTypes.h contain a vertexShader and samplingShader functions that are loaded by an AAPLRenderer.m

In the sample it's really straightforward

```
 id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary = [_device newDefaultLibrary];
    id<MTLFunction> vertexFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"vertexShader"];
    id<MTLFunction> fragmentFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"samplingShader"];
```

I have copied these files to a RayWenderlich Swift tutorial and used the swift version
There is an init to set the library

```
Renderer.library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
```

then

```
 let library = Renderer.library
    let importVertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertexShader")
    let importShaderFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "samplingShader")
```

This works just fine!

Same thing in my app with the same files copied over and it does not load the functions.

I have checked compileSources in build settings - it lists the metal file.
Comparing everything in settings and don't see a difference between the working apps and my app.

I don't see any error messages or log messages to indicate a syntax or path problem.

Any ideas?

The Apple sample code AAPLShaders.metal

```
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Metal shaders used for this sample
*/

#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <simd/simd.h>

using namespace metal;

// Include header shared between this Metal shader code and C code executing Metal API commands
#import "AAPLShaderTypes.h"

// Vertex shader outputs and per-fragment inputs. Includes clip-space position and vertex outputs
//  interpolated by rasterizer and fed to each fragment generated by clip-space primitives.
typedef struct
{
    // The [[position]] attribute qualifier of this member indicates this value is the clip space
    //   position of the vertex wen this structure is returned from the vertex shader
    float4 clipSpacePosition [[position]];

    // Since this member does not have a special attribute qualifier, the rasterizer will
    //   interpolate its value with values of other vertices making up the triangle and
    //   pass that interpolated value to the fragment shader for each fragment in that triangle;
    float2 textureCoordinate;

} RasterizerData;

// Vertex Function
vertex RasterizerData
vertexShader(uint vertexID [[ vertex_id ]],
             constant AAPLVertex *vertexArray [[ buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices) ]],
             constant vector_uint2 *viewportSizePointer  [[ buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize) ]])

{

    RasterizerData out;

    // Index into our array of positions to get the current vertex
    //   Our positions are specified in pixel dimensions (i.e. a value of 100 is 100 pixels from
    //   the origin)
    float2 pixelSpacePosition = vertexArray[vertexID].position.xy;

    // Get the size of the drawable so that we can convert to normalized device coordinates,
    float2 viewportSize = float2(*viewportSizePointer);

    // The output position of every vertex shader is in clip space (also known as normalized device
    //   coordinate space, or NDC). A value of (-1.0, -1.0) in clip-space represents the
    //   lower-left corner of the viewport whereas (1.0, 1.0) represents the upper-right corner of
    //   the viewport.

    // In order to convert from positions in pixel space to positions in clip space we divide the
    //   pixel coordinates by half the size of the viewport.
    out.clipSpacePosition.xy = pixelSpacePosition / (viewportSize / 2.0);

    // Set the z component of our clip space position 0 (since we're only rendering in
    //   2-Dimensions for this sample)
    out.clipSpacePosition.z = 0.0;

    // Set the w component to 1.0 since we don't need a perspective divide, which is also not
    //   necessary when rendering in 2-Dimensions
    out.clipSpacePosition.w = 1.0;

    // Pass our input textureCoordinate straight to our output RasterizerData. This value will be
    //   interpolated with the other textureCoordinate values in the vertices that make up the
    //   triangle.
    out.textureCoordinate = vertexArray[vertexID].textureCoordinate;
    
    return out;
}

// Fragment function
fragment float4
samplingShader(RasterizerData in [[stage_in]],
               texture2d<half> colorTexture [[ texture(AAPLTextureIndexBaseColor) ]])
{
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::linear,
                                      min_filter::linear);

    // Sample the texture to obtain a color
    const half4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample(textureSampler, in.textureCoordinate);

    // We return the color of the texture
    return float4(colorSample);
}
```

The Apple Sample code header AAPLShaderTypes.h

```
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Header containing types and enum constants shared between Metal shaders and C/ObjC source
*/

#ifndef AAPLShaderTypes_h
#define AAPLShaderTypes_h

#include <simd/simd.h>

// Buffer index values shared between shader and C code to ensure Metal shader buffer inputs match
//   Metal API buffer set calls
typedef enum AAPLVertexInputIndex
{
    AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices     = 0,
    AAPLVertexInputIndexViewportSize = 1,
} AAPLVertexInputIndex;

// Texture index values shared between shader and C code to ensure Metal shader buffer inputs match
//   Metal API texture set calls
typedef enum AAPLTextureIndex
{
    AAPLTextureIndexBaseColor = 0,
} AAPLTextureIndex;

//  This structure defines the layout of each vertex in the array of vertices set as an input to our
//    Metal vertex shader.  Since this header is shared between our .metal shader and C code,
//    we can be sure that the layout of the vertex array in the code matches the layout that
//    our vertex shader expects
typedef struct
{
    // Positions in pixel space (i.e. a value of 100 indicates 100 pixels from the origin/center)
    vector_float2 position;

    // 2D texture coordinate
    vector_float2 textureCoordinate;
} AAPLVertex;

#endif /* AAPLShaderTypes_h */
```

Debug print of my library

```
Printing description of self.library:
(MTLLibrary?) library = (object = 0x00006000004af7b0) {
  object = 0x00006000004af7b0 {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = CaptureMTLLibrary
    }
```

Debug print of working library from RayWenderlich sample app
The new added sampleShader and vertexShader are shown in the library along with the existing fragment and vertex functions.

```
▿ Optional<MTLLibrary>
  - some : <CaptureMTLLibrary: 0x600000f54210> -> <MTLDebugLibrary: 0x600002204050> -> <_MTLLibrary: 0x600001460280>
    label = <none> 
    device = <MTLSimDevice: 0x15a5069d0>
        name = Apple iOS simulator GPU 
    functionNames: fragment_main vertex_main samplingShader vertexShader
```

Comment: Is .metal file part of your project build? Is there a default.metallib inside your built product?

Comment: All three apps (Apple's BasicTexture, RayWenderlich Swift tutorial, my app) have three files in a Metal folder in the build directory.  extensions are .air, .dat, .dia  for the file AAPLShaders.  None of the apps have a .metallib file. Only my app is not loading the functions. Printing a debug description of the defaultLibrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer - issue of not loading functions into the metal library is resolved by removing a leftover  -fcikernel flag in the Other Metal Compiler Flags option of Build Settings of the project target.
The flag was set when testing a CoreImageKernel.metal as documented in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-init
I removed the kernel definition file from the app but missed the compiler flag.. and missed it when visually comparing build settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the target membership of file? Your code is nothing to weird so please check the target.

[image]

Comment: Yes, checked the type - it is correct 'Default - Metal Shader Source'. Good  suggestion.. just not the solution yet..